# Can't set model when rendering RazorPage in ASP.Net 5

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm building a project using the new ASP.Net 5/MVC 6 libraries and I've come to a part where I want to dynamically render a razor page to a string.

This is for a dynamic widget-system so the idea is to do this in an `ActionFilter` after generating the model but before rendering the main view.

The setup for it is quite large but it's mostly requiring services and putting pieces together (if someone knows a simpler way then please tell!).

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context) {
    var pageFactory = (IRazorPageFactory)context.HttpContext.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(IRazorPageFactory));
    var viewEngine = (IRazorViewEngine)context.HttpContext.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(IRazorViewEngine));
    var viewFactory = (IRazorViewFactory)context.HttpContext.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(IRazorViewFactory));
    var modelMetadataProvider = (IModelMetadataProvider)context.HttpContext.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(IModelMetadataProvider));

    var page = pageFactory.CreateInstance($"~/Views/Widgets/{widgetInfo.Type}.cshtml");
    var view = viewFactory.GetView(viewEngine, page, false);

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var sw = new StringWriter(sb);

    page.ViewContext = new ViewContext(new ActionContext(context.HttpContext, context.RouteData, context.ActionDescriptor), view, new ViewDataDictionary(modelMetadataProvider, new ModelStateDictionary()), sw);
```

After setting all this up I try to set the `Model`-property on my ViewData and I can see that I've set the correct object and that it is of the correct type for the page.

```
    page.ViewContext.ViewData.Model = widgetInfo.Setting;
```

I then execute the page which works great when I'm not using any models in my template.

```
    page.ExecuteAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    sw.Flush();

    var renderedWidget = sb.ToString();
```

I can see that my template is loaded (and even put breakpoints within it) but Model is always null. Currently I use this simple template.

```
@model DataObjects.CodeWidgetModel
@Html.Raw(Model.Code)
```

I've been scouring the [MVC6-sources](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/) over at GitHub to see what I could have missed but I can't find anything useful.

I'm running `ASP.Net MVC 6.0.0-beta3-12628` and `KRE 1.0.0-beta3-11014` but will most probably upgrade to beta4 as soon as it's available.

Anyone have any idea why setting `Model` on `ViewData` isn't enough or what else I need to do to get this working?

Comment: Why not just render the widgets into your main view as necessary via @Html.Action calls, or use templated views as your widgets via @Html.DisplayFor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more research (quite a lot of just trial and error to be honest) it seems that `RazorPage.ExecuteAsync()` wasn't the right method for this. Calling `RazorView.RenderAsync()` instead with a correctly typed `ViewDataDictionary<>` did the trick!

Below is the final code.

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context) {
    var pageFactory = (IRazorPageFactory)context.HttpContext.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(IRazorPageFactory));
    var viewEngine = (IRazorViewEngine)context.HttpContext.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(IRazorViewEngine));
    var viewFactory = (IRazorViewFactory)context.HttpContext.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(IRazorViewFactory));

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var sw = new StringWriter(sb);

    var page = pageFactory.CreateInstance($"~/Areas/Widgets/DefaultViews/Widgets/{widgetInfo.Type}.cshtml");
    var view = (RazorView)viewFactory.GetView(viewEngine, page, true);

    var vddType = typeof(ViewDataDictionary<>);
    var vddGeneric = vddType.MakeGenericType(widgetInfo.Model.GetType());
    dynamic viewDataDictionary = Activator.CreateInstance(vddGeneric, new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary());

    var actionContext = new ActionContext(context.HttpContext, context.RouteData, context.ActionDescriptor);
    var viewContext = new ViewContext(actionContext, view, viewDataDictionary, sw);
    viewContext.ViewData.Model = widgetInfo.Model;

    view.RenderAsync(viewContext).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    sw.Flush();

    var renderedWidget = sb.ToString();
}
```

I'm not particularly happy with the `dynamic` for `ViewDataDictionary` but it works. There might also be other ways to do this that are easier, but it's good enough for now.

Tested on `ASP.Net MVC 6.0.0-beta3-12628` and `KRE 1.0.0-beta3-11014`.

Comment: This is terribly useful code, but I think you might be better served with `ViewComponent`s. They are MVC6's solution for Partial Views, which sounds like what you're trying to do.

Comment: If I could use ViewComponents or any other part of MVC6 I would love to. I'm currently parsing out widget nodes from a html string (created in an WYSIWYG-editor) and then I need to render a specific View based on that which is then inserted into the html string again.
If I wanted to use ViewComponents or partials in some way I would need to execute the whole html string and I can't execute user generated razor templates on the fly since they can contain almost any kind of code.

Comment: I just built something like this myself for rendering HTML emails; you can use the non-generic `ViewDataDictionary` instead of needing to build the generic type with `Activator.CreateInstance`. I also used `ICompositeViewEngine` instead of the Razor interfaces directly.

Answer (score 1):

You are diving pretty deep into the rendering pipeline for something so simple.  Try creating your model with a widgets collection.  In your main view do something like:

`foreach(var widget in Model.Widgets) { Html.DisplayFor(widget) }`

Then create a view in /views/displaytemplates/widget.cshtml that then breaks the widget out into the correct template by casting it to the more specific type of widget and then calling Html.DisplayFor with it.

** PSEUDO code **

```
@model Widget
if (Widget is Widget1Type) Html.DisplayFor((Widget1Type)Widget)
if (Widget is Widget2Type) Html.DisplayFor((Widget2Type)Widget)
if (Widget is Widget3Type) Html.DisplayFor((Widget3Type)Widget)
if (Widget is Widget4Type) Html.DisplayFor((Widget4Type)Widget)
```

Then create your views for those widgets
/views/displaytemplates/widget1type:

```
@model Widget1Type
...Stuff here...
```

Comment: My main model currently has a dictionary with named content zones in it which contains raw html. In those html zones I have html-elements looking something like this `<widget id="code-widget-1" />` and is created by a user via an WYSIWYG-editor. The id is used with a separate dictionary to find the settings for the particular widget which then is used to render the widget. So I can't really use the regular rendering pipeline (and I really don't want to execute any code that a user might put into the html zones).

Comment: Thats way to old I'm afraid. I have no problem doing this in ASPNET4/MVC5, thats quite well documented around the web. It's doing it in the lastest ASPNET5/vNext thats eluding me.